# Pullback connection from a local diffeomorphism under an integral.

Tags: integration, riemannian-geometry, connections, diffeomorphism, pullback

Suppose $(M^n, g)$ and $(N^n,h)$ are Riemannian manifolds, and for each $p\in M$ there is a neighborhood $U\subset M$ and a diffeomorphism $\phi:(U, g|_U) \to (N,h)$  such that $g|_U = \phi^*h$. I only know this map exists, I don't have an explicit formula for it. Let $\nabla^g$ and $\nabla^h$ be the Levi-Civita connections of $M$ and $N$ respectively. For $u\in C^\infty(N)$ I want to evaluate the integral

$\int_N |\nabla^h u|^2 Vol_h$

by pulling everything back to $U\subset M$. I know that in this case, since $\phi(U) = N$ and $Vol_g = \phi^*(Vol_h)$ that, for example for $f\in C^\infty(M)$ we have

$\int_U f\, Vol_g = \int_{\phi^{-1}(N)} [(f \circ \phi^{-1})\circ \phi] \phi^*(Vol_h) = \int_{\phi^{-1}(N)} \phi^*[(f\circ \phi^{-1}) Vol_h] = \int_N (f\circ \phi^{-1}) Vol_h$

but I can't figure out how to pull this off with the connection in the first integral. Namely I need the $\nabla^h$ to turn into a $\nabla^g$ under $\phi$ somehow. I want to say something like $\nabla^g = \phi^*\nabla^h$ so that

$\int_N |\nabla^h u|^2 Vol_h = \int_{\phi(U)} |((\phi^{-1})^*\nabla^g)((u \circ\phi)\circ \phi^{-1})|^2 (\phi^{-1})^*(Vol_g) = \int_{\phi(U)} (\phi^{-1})^*[|\nabla^g(u\circ\phi)|^2 Vol_g] = \int_U |\nabla^g (u\circ\phi)|^2 Vol_g$

but the whole thing just looks so suspicious especially with the squared norm. I get that $|\nabla^h u|^2$ is just a smooth function on $N$ and it should pullback to M as just $|\nabla^h u|^2 \circ \phi$ but how can I use $\phi$ to transform $|\nabla^h u|^2$ into $|\nabla^g F|^2$ for some $F\in C^\infty(M)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to address this using pullback connections, but it isn't needed here: for any affine connection $\nabla$ and any $f\in C^\infty M$, we have $\nabla f=df$ by definition, and the differential obeys the pullback relation $\psi^*(df)=d(\psi^*f)$ for an arbitrary smooth map $\psi$.

From here, we have $\|\nabla u\|^2=\overline{h}(du,du)$, where $\overline {h}$ denotes the inverse of the metric $h$. By choosing an orthonormal basis $e_1,\cdots,e_n\in T_pM$, and using the fact that $\phi$ is an isometry, and thus the pushforwards $d_p\phi(e_1),\cdots,d_p\phi(e_n)$ form an orthonormal basis of $T_{\phi(p)}M$, we have
$$\begin{align*}
\overline g(d(\phi^*u),d(\phi^*u))|_p&=\sum_{i=1}^n[d(\phi^*u)(e_i)]^2 \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n[\phi^*(du)(e_i)]^2 \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n[du(d_p\phi(e_i))]^2 \\
&=\overline{h}(du,du)|_{\phi(p)}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: $\phi: (M,g) \to (N,h)$ diffeo, $u\in C^\infty(N)$ and $u\circ\phi \in C^\infty(M)$, $g=\phi^*h$,  $\partial_i$ a frame for TM and $\phi_{*} \partial_i =: \hat\partial_i$ for TN. So $d(u\circ\phi)(\partial_i) = g(\nabla^g(u\circ\phi), \partial_i) = (\phi^*h)(\nabla^g(u\circ\phi), \partial_i) = h(\phi_* (\nabla^g(u\circ\phi)), \phi_*\partial_i) =: h(\nabla^h u, \hat\partial_i) = du(\hat\partial_i)$? So by defn $\nabla^h u = \phi_* (\nabla^g(u\circ\phi))$?? Thanks for your help with my previous questions btw.

Comment: @piRskwayrd It's not clear to me what you're trying to say here.

Comment: $d(u\circ\phi)(\partial_i) = d(\phi^*u)(\partial_i) = (\phi^*(du))(\partial_i) =  du(\phi_*(\partial_i)) = du(\hat\partial_i)$ I was trying to use to definition $du(X) = h(\nabla^h u, X)$ and $d(u\circ\phi)(Y) = g(\nabla^g (u\circ\phi), Y)$ to find an expression for $\nabla^h$ in terms of $\nabla^g$. Isn't that what you meant by bringing up that $d$ commutes with pullbacks?

Comment: @piRskwayrd Ah. It seems that you're using $\nabla$ to denote the gradient rather than the covariant derivative. There's no need to use gradients, since $\|\operatorname{grad}u\|^2=g(\operatorname{grad}u,\operatorname{grad}u)=\overline{g}(du,du)$, where $\overline{g}$ denotes the inverse metric. I've added a bit which shows one way of doing this computation.